# SharePoint 2013 foundation installation and Hardening OS

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, installation

There is one requirement from my client to **install SharePoint 2013 foundation** on **Hardening OS** on Windows Server 2012 R2. Need to install it in only one-tier architecture.

After googling about Hardening OS, I came to know that Hardening OS is related to firewall security and it will provide the better security to the Server. Also it requires to block ports on the server or something related that. Also there is some requirement about SQL server Hardening. Also the ports that SQL server and SharePoint uses need to be opened for server communication.

It is very confusing for me after reading on internet as it is completely new topic for me.

My questions are:

- How to harden the **Windows Server 2012 R2** for SharePoint 2013 foundation installation? Need head to toe - all steps for hardening.
- Steps of installation after hardening the OS.
- Steps for SQL Server hardening.

I have referred below links for reference but couldn't able to get complete steps for **installation of SharePoint 2013 foundation with Hardening OS**.

- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262849.aspx
- http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint-2010/sharepoint-security-server-hardening
- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/jj720323.aspx
- https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/praveenh/2013/02/27/farm-communication-in-sharepoint/